# "exp_module_member_groups' doesn't exist" on uninstalling add-on

Tags: ee6

I am getting the error while uninstalling the Addon in EE6.

"exp_module_member_groups' doesn't exist"

Comment: Questions about add-ons are easier to answer if you include the version number of the add-on in your question.

Answer (score 1):

If the add-on has version that's EE6-compatible (and it's available to you), you should first update it and then uninstall.

Having said that, removing record from `exp_module_member_groups` is usually the last step for uninstall, so if you see add-on removed for the list then you're probably good to go.

Answer (score 0):

In EE6, `exp_module_member_groups` table is now renamed as `exp_module_member_roles`

look like the addon is not compatible with EE6. You have to rename the table `exp_module_member_groups` to `exp_module_member_roles` in the `upd` file of the addon.